# CSS doesn't modify the html page

Tags: html, css

I have this html code:

```
<div id="home-page"> hello from home</div>

<div class="home-page top-div">

    some text

</div>


<div class="home-page bottom-div">

    other text

</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#home-page {
    .top-div {
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #009900;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .bottom-div {
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #990000;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```

What I want to get is a page split in two parts horizontally, the top part in one colour and the second one in another colour. I tried this but it has no effect on my page.

Does anybody know what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: With normal css, you can't use nested CSS...

Comment: `#home2-page .top-div` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define #home2-page also as

```
#home2-page{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using percent in height is dependent on parent div height. If no height is set in the parent div, then height has no meaning.

The same is true for the parent. If you use a percent-height (or no height depending on `HTMLElement.style.display`) in the parent element, then *it's* parent needs to have a fixed height. All the way up to the html-element, which you *can* set to 100% height (and then it should work). `html{ height: 100% }`

Anyway, that is a silly way to do things, so I suggest you use something slightly more modern instead; The `vh` `vw` units (viewport height, viewport width).  One `vh` unit is 1% of the viewport height. Thus, you can replace `50%` with `50vh` and it'll be something closer to what you wish for.

```
.top-div {
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
 html,body {
    height: 100%;
  }

.top-div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009900;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.bottom-div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #990000;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="home2-page"> hello from home</div>

<div class="home2-page top-div">

    some text

</div>


<div class="home2-page bottom-div">

    other text

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @C Travel said, you can't use nested CSS meaning you can't put a class inside a class. You can accomplish your goal by simplifying your code a bit. Checkout my working example below:

CSS:

```
<style>

.top-div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #009900;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

.bottom-div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #990000;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top-div">

    <p>hello from home</p>
    <p>some text</p>

</div>

<div class="bottom-div">

    <p>other text</p>

</div>
```